# Filling input by clicking on the checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input that can be filled in by searching for an item, or by clicking on the checkbox. When you click on the checkbox, input must be filled with the default value `valueText`. How to check the checkbox selection and set the value to `[ngModel]`.

```js
 public foundedElement: Element[];
 public defaultValue: boolean;
 public valueText = "text";

 constructor(public elementFacade: ElementFacade) {}

 addField(value) {
    return currentElement.field = value;
 }

 searchElement(e): void {
    const {value} = e.target;
    if (value.length > 1) {
      this.elementFacade.getAll({name: value}).subscribe(el => this.foundedElement = el);
    }
  }
```

```html
 <input-container>
       <input #elementInput
              [mdAutocomplete]="autoElement"
              (input)="searchElement($event)"
              [ngModel]="currentElement ? currentElement.field : ''"
       />
       <md-autocomplete #autoElement="mdAutocomplete">
         <md-option
           *ngFor="let el of foundedElement"
           (onSelectionChange)="addField(el.name)">
           {{el.name}}
         </md-option>
       </md-autocomplete>
     </input-container>
      <md-checkbox  [checked]="defaultValue">Default</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: What should happen if the user unselects the checkbox? Will the input be cleared too? Also, are you using AngularJS (Angular v1.x)?

Comment: the user selects an item from the `md-option`, if user clicks the checkbox, then the value `valueText`.  (Angular 4)

Comment: I see.. Ok because `md-checkbox` is a syntax from AngularJS Material. That is why I was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to add the `(change)` event in the checkbox so whenever you press it, it changes the value of the input:

```
<md-checkbox  [checked]="defaultValue" (change)="onCheckChange()">Default</md-checkbox>
```

And in your ts you add the function:

```
  onCheckChange() {
    this.inputValue = valueText;
  }
```

Where `this.inputValue` It's the `ngModel` of the input that you want to change. In your scenario if the input is the #elementInput, then you should have something like:

```
onCheckChange() {
    this.currentElement.field  = valueText;
  }
```

With this approach it only gonna change once, because of the declaration of the ngModel in that field. 
To solve that you could do two things:

1. Use the `[(ngModel)]` with a property without operations.
2. Use `(ngModelChange)` to refresh the value of `this.currentElement.field`

**You can check the live example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-checkbox-55528725?file=src/app/input/input.component.html

Comment: perfect! 
how to clear `input` when `defaultValue` === false

Comment: Do you mean checking just the defaultValue o when they change the value of the checkbox to see the state? If it is only to check the initialValue, then I would change just this line: `this.currentElement.field  = valueText;` to this one: `this.currentElement.field  = this.defaultValue? this.valueText : '';`